# Get comments of Post (one to many relation)

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

One to many relationship.

I want to get the comment of the post where both are in the same table named post, but the comments has data on a `parent` column (parent post)

I am from PHP and using laravel i would just `$this->hasMany('post','parent');`

But in django how do I do this?

To return all the comments of that post. must show the post and have an attribute comments, and show the comments there.

Comment: show us your models.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as you can read here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/relations/

A “related manager” is a manager used in a one-to-many or many-to-many related context. This happens in two cases:

The “other side” of a ForeignKey relation. That is:

```
from django.db import models

class Reporter(models.Model):
    # ...
    pass

class Article(models.Model):
    reporter = models.ForeignKey(Reporter)
```

In the above example, the methods below will be available on the manager `reporter.article_set`.

In your case is `post.post_set`. If you don't like `post_set` you can specify the `related_name` in the ForeignKey:

```
parent = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name='comments')
```

At this point you can query: `post.comments`